# how to properly cache data in a self-hosted WebAPI application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# WebAPI application, self-hosted with TopShelf.
I need to optimize some of my data access by querying a few databases upon application start-up, and then caching the results (which are static) for any subsequent access by my WebAPI controllers.
My solution consists of two projects:

ServiceHub.Topshelf.WebAPI (which contains all business logic) and  Topshelf.WebPI (whic only hosts WebApiConfigurator.cs)

What is the proper technique for doing this type of data caching?

Comment: have you looked at the `Cache` class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think I got it - will post as an answer now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Ric suggested, I've looked at the Cache class. Here is what I did in my SIgnedContractsController.csc to accomplish the caching:

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;
.....
ObjectCache cache;
List<Model.SignedContracts> allSignedContracts;
.....

cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            allSignedContracts = cache["signed_contracts"] as List<Model.SignedContracts>;

            if (allSignedContracts == null)
            {
                allSignedContracts = new List<Model.SignedContracts>();
                CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1.0);
                var result = (from contracts in new XPQuery<Model.SignedContracts>(uow) select contracts);
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    allSignedContracts.Add(item); 
                }
                cache.Add("signed_contracts",allSignedContracts,policy);

            }
```

Then, in the GET method I did this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {

            var _americasPriorWeekThree = Convert.ToInt32((from contracts in allSignedContracts
                                                           where contracts.Region == "Americas"
                                                       select contracts.PriorWeek3).First());
```

.......

Comment: Nice one. Doing this kind of thing is quite common.